# Use one image for different buttons state

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want create ImageButton with image on it with two states - normal and pressed. States use the same image, but in pressed state it more lighter. Is it possible do with XML only, without two images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that I am satisfied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_image" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_image_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

On button background I put this drawable, where `my_image` image from resources and `my_image_pressed` next drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="#5FEC" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: not an ideal solution. This will depend on how your image is sized. If it is round cornered, then this solution will look bad.

Comment: Thanks buddy i got this solution about single image set on button selector :)

Answer (score 1):

But Why you don't want to use two different images?

Comment: You can't use combination of image and color in button.

Comment: You can reduce the file size of your button images by making 9-Patch images. Also, you really should have 5 states for buttons (normal, focused, pressed, disabled_focused, and disabled), so you may as well bite the bullet and expect to have lots of resources. I would make them as small as reasonably possible and, depending on your design constraints, see if you can consolidate the number of different buttons you need.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:create xml file in drawable folder named selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lighter_image"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_image"/>

 </selector>
```

On imageButton set background as this xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: That will be 2 images, he searches for a solution with just 1 image for both states. Although I don't see any other solution than yours.

Comment: he has to create two images.he cant manage it programatically.and what is problem in making two images.one should think of getting out the problem through any way

Comment: And what is @drawable/lighter_image and @drawable/original_image?

Comment: original_image is the one you have and lighter_image is the same image just having color lighter than your original_image.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want use 2 images

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a ColorFilter to the ImageButton's image in onDraw when the state is pressed. And clear it when it's not pressed.

```
filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(0x7FFFFFFF, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (isPressed())
    {
        getDrawable().setColorFilter(filter);
    }
    else
    {
        getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
    }
}
```